# ASP MVC 5 Not getting a collection posted back to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So far I can't figure out what is not working with my ViewModel and controller, since I have followed some examples on StackOverflow but for some reason my model is not filling up. Here is my Get and Post Controller Methods

```
public ActionResult Registrar(DateTime FechaTarja, long HaciendaId, long[] Pedidos)
{
    if(Pedidos != null && Pedidos.Length > 0)
    {
       List<RegistroPedidoTarjaViewModel> data = new List<RegistroPedidoTarjaViewModel>();
       foreach (long Pedido in Pedidos)
       {
          data.Add(new RegistroPedidoTarjaViewModel {
              PedidoEmbarqueId = Pedido
       });
     }
     return View(new RegistroTarjaViewModel {
         HaciendaId = HaciendaId,
         FechaTarja = FechaTarja,
         Pedidos = data
     });
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { FechaTarja = FechaTarja.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), HaciendaId = HaciendaId });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registrar(RegistroTarjaViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
    return View(model);
}
```

My View Model

```
public class RegistroTarjaViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public long HaciendaId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime FechaTarja { get; set; }
    public List<RegistroPedidoTarjaViewModel> Pedidos { get; set; }
    public long? ContenedorId { get; set; }
}
```

My Razor View

```
@model Project.ViewModels.RegistroTarjaViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registrar Nueva Tarja";
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FechaTarja)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HaciendaId)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">

        </div>
    </div>
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Pedidos.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Pedidos[i].PedidoEmbarqueId)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pedidos[i].Embarcadas, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pedidos[i].Embarcadas, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pedidos[i].Embarcadas, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Registrar Tarja" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

I am getting posted back the HaciendaId and FechaTarja properties, but not the Pedidos List, what am I missing to include on the Controller?

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the HTML output of the textbox

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="El campo Embarcadas debe ser un número." data-val-required="El campo Embarcadas es obligatorio." id="Pedidos_0__Embarcadas" name="Pedidos[0].Embarcadas" type="text" value="0">
```

Comment: What is the html generated by `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pedidos[i].Embarcadas, new { @class = "form-control" })`?

Comment: There is a good article you may wish to read: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Comment: @IamNguele I have edited the question including an example of the output

Comment: @Milney From what I have read, I assume I have to use a different ViewModel for the Post action that implements an array instead of a List of values. I still feel kind of lost on how to extend/modify my ViewModel

Comment: You have not shown your `RegistroPedidoTarjaViewModel` model, but assuming it contains public properties (not fields), then your code works just fine. If its not its due to code you have not shown us.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. Here is how I tested -

View is same as yours.

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Registrar()
    {
        List<RegistroPedidoTarjaViewModel> data = new List<RegistroPedidoTarjaViewModel>();
        data.Add(new RegistroPedidoTarjaViewModel {PedidoEmbarqueId = 1, Embarcadas = "One"});
        data.Add(new RegistroPedidoTarjaViewModel {PedidoEmbarqueId = 2, Embarcadas = "Two"});
        data.Add(new RegistroPedidoTarjaViewModel {PedidoEmbarqueId = 3, Embarcadas = "Three"});
        data.Add(new RegistroPedidoTarjaViewModel {PedidoEmbarqueId = 4, Embarcadas = "Four"});

        return View(new RegistroTarjaViewModel
        {
            HaciendaId = 1,
            FechaTarja = DateTime.Now,
            Pedidos = data
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Registrar(RegistroTarjaViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**View Models**

```
public class RegistroTarjaViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public long HaciendaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime FechaTarja { get; set; }

    public List<RegistroPedidoTarjaViewModel> Pedidos { get; set; }
    public long? ContenedorId { get; set; }
}

public class RegistroPedidoTarjaViewModel
{
    public long PedidoEmbarqueId { get; set; }
    public string Embarcadas { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

**Posted Result**
[image]

Comment: For some reason I'm receiving Pedidos as null, the ModelBinder is not working as intended

Comment: You might want to create a brand new ASP.NET MVC Project, and copy and paste the above code.